# Azure function app deployment through intellij

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy azure function app from intelliJ, getting following error when run mvn azure-functions:deploy

"The specified function app does not exist. Creating a new function app..."

after above getting status code : 400

Not sure why 400 since there is nothing printed or returned.

Answer (score 1):

In pom, check `functionResourceGroup` of `properties`, resource group has some [naming restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#general)

> Alphanumeric, underscore, parentheses, hyphen, period (except at end), and Unicode characters that match the allowed characters.

Maven Plugin for Azure Functions seems not to provide concrete error message as it does for `functionAppName`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had multiple subscriptions attached to my account, since I was not setting any subscription upon login, azure was using default subscription and was not finding the function app.

I set the subscription in which function app was created then it worked properly.

az login -u <> -p <>

and then set the subscription

az account set

after above run the azure deploy. it worked for me.